# pyarmor strange behaviour

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyarmor

I have a project with 2 main .py files. One of the files is basically a stripped down version of the other. I have 2 spec files for each individual .py file and i am running the commands:

```
pyarmor pack -s file1.spec file1.py
pyarmor pack -s file2.spec file2.py
```

and ALWAYS one of the exe files has very weird character display. The accented letters or the box special characters for console are a mess.

If i run pyinstaller with my own parameters (which built the spec files i have) both exe files display all characters perfectly, but when i use pyarmor it messes things up for one of them.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

After testing absolutely everything, i found out how to solve it.

Even if I'm using python 3.9 and it's supposed to be using utf-8 by default, even when the spec file says that python coding is utf-8, you MUST add the coding utf-8 at the very beginning of the py files you are packing or sometimes, randomly, it will pack them as ascii and have weird symbols all over the place.